# Quartz.net : how build Cron expression for few special days of every year

Tags: quartz.net

for example : run job at 10/4 and 11/7 and 15/12 in every year.
How build Cron expression for that?

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. What have you tried?

Comment: you need to create three different triggers e.g. `"0 0 0 10 4 ?"` (assuming you want to execute cron at midnight. on 10/4)

Comment: I think this is a duplicate question that was answered [here][1].


  [1]: http://serverfault.com/questions/339814/how-do-you-set-a-date-variable-to-use-in-a-log-for-crontab-output

Comment: With single cron expression it is not possible,you have to create no of cron expression based on your no of days.

Comment: so,creating three different triggers is solution. Is it possible that one trigger relate multi Cron expression?